# No rule to make something.o even though %.o is defined

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to the forum, so I hope I'm doing things right.

I'm writing from scratch a Makefile for a C project. It was working at some point, then I tried to improve it a little (including separate folders), and I got the well-known error "No rule to make target "obj/autresFonctions.o", needed for "CUR"". Or similar, since it's not in english and I translated.

That seems quite weird since the rule I'm expecting to work is using %.o and should match anyhting. Thus I don't think it could be a typo.

Here is the Makefile :

```
EXE=prgm
CC=gcc

SRC_DIR=src
OBJ_DIR=obj
INCLUDE_DIR=include

_FICHIERS_H = autresFonctions.h calculPrealable.h constantes.h fonctionsAnnexes.h fonctionBoucles.h lectureFichiers.h main.h
FICHIERS_H = $(patsubst %, $(INCLUDE_DIR)/%, $(_FICHIERS_H))

_OBJ = autresFonctions.o calculPrealable.o fonctionsAnnexes.o fonctionsBoucles.o lectureFichiers.o main.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %, $(OBJ_DIR)/%, $(_OBJ))


FLAGS=-Wall -Wextra



CUR: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(EXE) $^

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(FICHIERS_H)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $< 

clean:
    rm $(OBJ) $(EXE)
```

I'm assuming it's the same for the others .o, because I also tried switching the first two .o in _OBJ , and I got the same error with calculPrealable.o

I'm just typing "make" when compiling, in order to get CUR, the main target. I'm located in the main directory, which contains include/ (with the .h), src/ (with the .c) and obj/ (empty).

EDIT : I forgot to say, but I'm using the usual GNU make.

Comment: This seems to be ok (with the GNU make). What make are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern rule only matches if ALL of the rule matches.  It's not enough to just match the target: make must also be able to find (or make) the prerequisite pattern(s) and all other prerequisites listed in the rule.

If one thing doesn't match, then the rule doesn't match.

You can use `make -d` to see what files make is trying to build, and see which one doesn't exist and causes the rule to fail.

PS. This is all assuming you're using GNU make, which you don't say specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. It tells me (especially 'make --debug=v' since 'make -d' is awfully huge) that obj/autresFonctions.o doesn't exist thus it's needed to be rebuilt, but that there is no rule to do so. Not much more info, sorry. I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: Well, if you turn off the debugging output that's relevant to your problem then you can't expect to get any useful details from the debugging information :-).  Yes, I know it's a lot of output, but turning it off won't help you solve your problem!!  You need, at the very least, the "implicit" level of debugging since the problem is with implicit rules.  Redirect the output to a file then after it's done search it for `obj/autresFonctions.o` and see what it says.  Most likely either `src/autresFonctions.c` or one of the header files doesn't exist.

Comment: FIXED ! Debugging output didn't help me much, but looking closely, there was indeed a 's' missing in "fonctionsBoucles" as we can see when comparing the .h and the .o in what I provided.

Comment: In the debugging output it would have printed something about trying to build `fonctionBoucles.h` and that would have failed, then it would have given up on the rule altogether.  That's what you were looking for.

Comment: By the way, your method here is very unusual.  What you're basically saying is that any time any header file is changed, ALL object files have to be rebuilt.  It may be true that all your source files include all your header files, but this is not typically the way programs work.

Comment: Worth noting: watch for the path. Mine had a .. in the beginning, the folder was inside instead :/